# Send data to server from app using Volley (Server has error )

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I generated app that connect to server, but it has below error and can't register data to server.My code is below. After googling, I know it is a server  error, but I don’t know where is mistake.
 Plz check out it and help me. TNX

Error is:

```
Volley: [223] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for https://xxxxx.com/set.php
```

ApplicationController class:

```
public class ApplicationController extends Application {
    /**
     * Log or request TAG
     */
    public static final String TAG = "VolleyPatterns";

    /**
     * Global request queue for Volley
     */
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    /**
     * A singleton instance of the application class for easy access in other places
     */
    private static ApplicationController sInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // initialize the singleton
        sInstance = this;
    }

    /**
     * @return ApplicationController singleton instance
     */
    public static synchronized ApplicationController getInstance() {
        return sInstance;
    }

    /**
     * @return The Volley Request queue, the queue will be created if it is null
     */
    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        // lazy initialize the request queue, the queue instance will be
        // created when it is accessed for the first time
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    /**
     * Adds the specified request to the global queue, if tag is specified
     * then it is used else Default TAG is used.
     * 
     * @param req
     * @param tag
     */
    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        // set the default tag if tag is empty
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);

        VolleyLog.d("Adding request to queue: %s", req.getUrl());

        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    /**
     * Adds the specified request to the global queue using the Default TAG.
     * 
     * @param req
     * @param tag
     */
    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        // set the default tag if tag is empty
        req.setTag(TAG);

        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    /**
     * Cancels all pending requests by the specified TAG, it is important
     * to specify a TAG so that the pending/ongoing requests can be cancelled.
     * 
     * @param tag
     */
    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

Main method to send data:

```
public void Send(View v) {
            try {
                  final String URL = "xxxxxx";
                 // Post params to be sent to the server
                HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("id", "8");
                params.put("name", "divid");
                params.put("email", "aa@my.com");
                params.put("date", "2010-08-08 21:31:01");
                params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

                JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(URL, new JSONObject(params),
                        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                try {
                                    VolleyLog.v("Response:%n %s", response.toString(4));
                                } catch (JSONException e) {                                
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
                        if (networkResponse != null) {
                            Log.i("err0rMsg", "Volley -> Error. HTTP Status Code:"+networkResponse.statusCode);
                        }

                        if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                            Log.i("err0rMsg", "Volley -> TimeoutError");
                        }else if(error instanceof NoConnectionError){
                            Log.i("err0rMsg", "Volley -> NoConnectionError");
                        } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                            Log.i("err0rMsg", "Volley -> AuthFailureError");
                        } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                            Log.i("err0rMsg", "Volley -> ServerError");
                        } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                            Log.i("err0rMsg", "Volley -> NetworkError");
                        } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                            Log.i("err0rMsg", "Volley -> ParseError");
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Server side:

```
<?php
         header( "Content-type: application/json" );
        $sitename = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        $hostname = "localhost";
        $username = "xxxxxxxx";
        $password = "xxxxxxxx";
        $database = "xxxxxxxxx";
        $tbl_name = "xxxxxxxx";
        $error = array();

    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $obj = json_decode($json, TRUE);

            $id = intval($obj['id']);
            $name = $obj[‘name’];
            $email  = $obj[‘email’];
            $date = $obj['date'];

            $query="INSERT INTO ".$tbl_name."(id, name, email, date) VALUES(".$id.", '".$name.
                        "', '".$email."', '".$date."')";

                $connect = @mysqli_connect( $hostname , $username , $password , $database );
                if( $connect )
                {
                    @mysqli_query( $connect , "SET CHARACTER SET utf8;" );

                    @mysqli_query( $connect , $query );

                    if( @mysqli_affected_rows( $connect ) > 0 )
                    {
                        $error['error'] = "done";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        @unlink( $location );

                        $error['error'] = "failure_inserting_database!";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    @unlink( $location );

                    $error['error'] = "failure_connecting_database";
                }
            } 
        die ( json_encode( $error['error'] ) );
?>
```

Comment: Remove the code from php script. Only echo some strings. Then look if you get those strings in the Android app as response. Do not use die() for it.

Comment: TNX, I done your suggestion. changed php script to below script:       <?php         echo "<h1>Hello!</h1>";         ?>  , but now it has this error: "Volley -> ParseError"

Comment: If you do a json request the php script should return json text. Not some html tags. So echo an encoded json array. Anyhow you have no 500 error anymore. So we can conclude that the php script caused a php crash.

Comment: I removed html tage. Now the script is: <?php  echo "Hello!";  ?> , but till it has error: "Volley -> ParseError". i know a litle php.....TNX alot

Comment: Of course. Because it is no json text. Volley tries to parse a response text which it considers to be a json text. You shoud echo some json array text. Like you did before. Someting like echo(json_encode( $error['error']);. And initialise the array before.

Comment: i got it !!!! changed the script to <?php
$json='{"number": 12345678901234567890}';
  echo $json ;
?>   and it response.... TNX--- now about insert data, where is wrong...

Comment: Well as the connection is ok now add code line by code line to your php script. Echo as much data as possible using isset() to check if a variable exists. Just try to echo the received data back first. Do nothing with the database yet. Just try step by step. You will find out soon enough which staetment causes the crash.

Comment: What you could do is only these two lines in your php script: `$json = file_get_contents('php://input'); echo($json);`. Then you will see what comes in.

Comment: Dear greenapps , $json = file_get_contents('php://input'); echo($json); ..is ok

Comment: Dear greenapps.....  I added code line by code line to my php script, and my problem solved. TNX alot